# How can I debug the source code of .Net Core or the Base class libraries (coreFx)?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, debug-symbols

I am using `.NET Core 1.0` and `Visual Studio 2015 Update 3` to make a simple Asp.Net Core MVC website.

How can I debug my application and "Step Into" the .NET Core [source code](https://github.com/aspnet/) that is available on GitHub?

Specifically, I am trying to troubleshoot one issue with `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Facebook` 1.0.0 assembly that I fetched from NuGet.

Comment: This shows you how to debug ASP.NET Core source code:
https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-debug-asp-net-core-source-code-448544c16473?sk=58f24ef1f6b39d0bd2927cd36dbd690c

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Update to fit new VS 2017**

In Visual Studio 2017 15.3.5 and later
We can use SourceLink support for debugging .NET Core and ASP.NET Core sources.
[image: vs 2017 options enable source link]
To enable source link support just Disable **Enable Just My Code** and and Enable **Enable Source Link Support**.
Then Enable Microsoft symbol servers.
[image: vs 2017 options enable symbol servers]

---

Victors answers works well with vs 2015.For some one who is looking for a solution with vs 2017,
In vs 2017 there is no global.json availble.So instead of adding folder path in global.json a project reference has to be added and rebuild.
All the others mentioned in Victors article works same as with 2015.

It is important that the git hub tag and the nuget package matches have the same versions.

Comment: How do you put a breakpoint in the source code though? If you try to go to an ASP.NET Core class it just says [from metadata] in the tab and shows you the method signatures only.

Answer (score 11):

I wrote [this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2015/02/06/debugging-asp-net-5-framework-code-using-visual-studio-2015/) more than 1 year ago so it's a bit out of date but the idea is still the same:

1. You sync to the correct tag from GitHub. In your case, you probably want to sync to [tag 1.0.0](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/tree/1.0.0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Facebook)
2. Build that repository by running `build.cmd` or `build.sh`
3. Add the `src` folder path to your app's `global.json` file. For example, if you cloned `Security` in `D:\Security`, then you add `D:/Security/src` to `global.json` in the `projects` property.
4. Rebuild everything and it should work.

PS: If you use VS and don't see immediately the new code, try restarting it. It's a known issue that sometimes it doesn't pick up the changes to `global.json`

Comment: It works! Thank you! Somehow your post didn't showed up when I googled it.

Comment: How would you do this for the core foundation libraries https://github.com/dotnet/corefx. 
Such if i just wanted to create a console app to test how the Linq namespace worked

Comment: @jw56578 It's the same process. Just clone the [corefx repo](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx), sync to the correct tag (that might be a bit hard to find) and the add the src folder to `project.json`

Comment: @VictorHurdugaci how to do it in VS2017? Project.json file is no longer exists.

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure that on a solution level, you have your project "configration", set to debug. See screenshot. 
. 
[image].

(For the solution properties to show up, right click on the .sln in the solution explorer.)

Answer (score 0):

If you have debugged an app before with the previous version of .NET, delete the `%TEMP%/SymbolCache` directory as it can have old PDBs that are out of date. Per [Debug .NET and ASP.NET Core source code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/debug-aspnetcore-source)