# How can I debug the source code of .Net Core (not ASP.net Core)?

Tags: .net-core

I see that there is a simple solution to enable me to debug ASP.Net Core source Code (https://stackoverflow.com/a/38450697/6618773). But for me this doesn't work for the .Net Core assemblies from the corefx repository on Github. Is there a solution for this? Thanks a lot.